# Java.util.UUID is saving as BLOB in Mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

```
public class Test{
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name="TEST_ID",columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    @Type(type="uuid-binary")
    //@Column(name="TEST_ID",columnDefinition = "BINARY(32)")
    //@Type(type="uuid-char")
    private UUID testId;

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name="USER_ID",columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    //@Column(name="USER_ID",columnDefinition = "BINARY(32)")
    //@Type(type="uuid-binary") //@Type(type="uuid-char")
    private UUID userId;

    public void setTestId(UUID testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }

    public UUID getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }    

}
```

Save the data in the DB. 
The UUID is saving as BLOB in the DB. 
Error while getting the ID from the DB

```
test.setTestId( UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes((byte[]) row[0]));
```

Mysql Table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DBName`.`testtable` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DBName`.`testtable` (
`test_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
`user_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
`company_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `company_test_id` (`company_id`, `test_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

solutions tried :

```
//@Column(name="TEST_ID",columnDefinition = "BINARY(32)")
//@Type(type="uuid-binary") //@Type(type="uuid-char")
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: Get Query by testID is not working as expected.
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select fd.test_id, fd.company_id " +
                " from testtable tt" +
                " where tt.company_id = :companyid and tt.test_id = :testId ");
        q.setParameter("companyid",companyid);
        q.setParameter("testId",testId);
  How to use Unhex in this Hibernate query